# Has the step counter been recalibrated with iPhone 7 or iOS 10?

Tags: iphone, ios, health.app

I walk the same route to work each day, however, I have noticed that recently I am doing 500 - 1000 steps less each journey. This is an upto 25% difference.

I haven't noticed at what point this happened, and if it was gradual, but it is certainly lower since upgrading from my iPhone 6 on iOS 9 to an iPhone 7 on iOS 10.

I am walking the same route, wearing the same shoes and keep my iPhone in the same pocket. Have I lost these 1000 steps, or was it over-reading before?

Comment: I have nothing but anecdote for this - but using identical 6S's  my partner & I can be together all day, make the same journeys & at the end of the day record 2 different step and distance counts; enough that one of them must be wrong. I always seem to have walked further.

Comment: @Tetsujin Do you and your partner have identical stride length? You should expect two different people who have walked the same distance to have different step counts.

Comment: No, I'm slightly taller, but not much. Step counts I expect to be different - though they are too different & often show she has walked fewer steps. Even so I would expect total distance covered to be similar.

Comment: Honestly: It's a bit funny that people expect the step counter to be precise. This is just a gimmick, not a scientific equipment - nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 2):

**The motion coprocessor is a different version in the iPhone 7.**

Embedded within the A10 chip, there is another chip, called the motion coprocessor, M10. The new version of the coprocessor is likely to account for these errors in step counting.

In addition, this step counting is really only supposed to be an estimate. If you want an actually somewhat accurate step tracking solution, you should go for a dedicated wearable device, like a FitBit or Apple Watch.

The motion coprocessor is simply a gimmick to match competitors' phones.

Comment: I’m not clear how a fitbit or an apple watch would be more accurate than your phone?

Comment: Those are dedicated health devices that will be worn all day by users in the intended manner, whereas a phone can be set down, walked with out of your pocket, or otherwise worn in an abnormal way that the step counter may not recognize. A watch, for example, is always worn on your wrist all day (with few exceptions)